# How can I easily implement right-to-left text direction with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, right-to-left

My question is in the title. Can you help me to implement better solution for right-to-left text direction.

Comment: Is your question "How to load the good css depending on the locale?". For the moment, is sounds like "Can you help me solving a problem ?"

Comment: Sorry for my English. I don't need css for this, because I know how to make rtl for a page with css and twig template. It's pretty easy to check rtl flag in the template and add dir="rtl". But where can I store the rtl flag in symfony2? Parameters with locales?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can make something like this

```
<?php

namespace You\YourBundle\Constants;

    class LanguageConstants
    {
        const LANGUAGE_EN = 1;
        const LANGUAGE_HR = 2;
        const LANGUAGE_SR = 3;
        const LANGUAGE_BS = 4;
        const LANGUAGE_DE = 5;
        const LANGUAGE_PT = 6;
        const LANGUAGE_AR = 7;

        static private $constants = array(
            self::LANGUAGE_EN => 'English',
            self::LANGUAGE_HR => 'Hrvatski',
            self::LANGUAGE_SR => 'Srpski / Српски',
            self::LANGUAGE_BS => 'Bosanski / Босански',
            self::LANGUAGE_DE => 'Deutsch',
            self::LANGUAGE_PT => 'Português',
            self::LANGUAGE_AR => 'العربية',
        );

        static private $constantsURL = array(
            self::LANGUAGE_EN => 'en',
            self::LANGUAGE_HR => 'hr',
            self::LANGUAGE_SR => 'sr',
            self::LANGUAGE_BS => 'bs',
            self::LANGUAGE_DE => 'de',
            self::LANGUAGE_PT => 'pt',
            self::LANGUAGE_AR => 'ar',
        );

        static private $constantsRTL = array(
            self::LANGUAGE_EN => false,
            self::LANGUAGE_HR => false,
            self::LANGUAGE_SR => false,
            self::LANGUAGE_BS => false,
            self::LANGUAGE_DE => false,
            self::LANGUAGE_PT => false,
            self::LANGUAGE_AR => true,
        );

        static public function getLanguageConstants()
        {
            natsort(self::$constants);
            return self::$constants;
        }

        static public function getLanguageName($const)
        {
            return self::$constants[$const];
        }

        static public function getLanguageURL($const)
        {
            return self::$constantsURL[$const];
        }

        static public function getLanguageRTL($const)
        {
            return self::$constantsRTL[$const];
        }
    }
```

So, this is one way to go. This way you can have all your language data in one place, you can easily get en in yoururl/en/yourroute by calling getLanguageURL, and in same maner you can call getLanguageRTL in your controller with a proper _local and pass in to twig so that you could do if R2L true then dir=rtl.

You can even make a twig extension to call getLanguageRTL from twig but since controller is the place to do all "dirty works", why bother.

Best regards